# File not found in R raster loop

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Here I am trying to import tiff files of CT images to R for analysis. I have about 250 tiff files that I am trying to analyze on a loop. The analysis starts by cropping, then thresholding, then calculating porosity based on pixel intensity values. Currently I am getting this error:

`Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)`

```
`library(raster)
 library(rgdal)
 library(sp)`


    `project_files <- dir("/Users/Rob/Documents/BMBT5130/Data")
    for (jj in 1:length(mget(project_files)))  {
    x[jj] <- raster(paste0(project_files[jj]))
    x1 <- crop(x, extent(800,1600,700,1600))
    x[x<=35]=0
    plot(x1)
    Porosity[jj] <- (length(x1[x1<=35]))/length(x1[x1>=0])`
```

The working directory is the directory used above

Sessioninfo:

`R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6`

`locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base`

`other attached packages:
 [1] RBioFormats_0.0.30 rJava_0.9-8        EBImage_4.16.0     imager_0.40.2      magrittr_1.5
 [6] plyr_1.8.4         ROI_0.2-1          rgdal_1.2-6        raster_2.5-8       sp_1.2-4
[11] tiff_0.1-5`

`loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10        knitr_1.15.1        BiocGenerics_0.20.0 lattice_0.20-35     jpeg_0.1-8
 [6] stringr_1.2.0       tools_3.3.3         parallel_3.3.3      grid_3.3.3          png_0.1-7
[11] registry_0.3        abind_1.4-5         bmp_0.2             purrr_0.2.2         fftwtools_0.9-8
[16] slam_0.1-40         readbitmap_0.1-4    stringi_1.1.5       locfit_1.5-9.1`

Any help fixing this will be much appreciated.
Best,
Rob

Comment: Try to replace `dir` with `list.files`.

Comment: Thank you, the error I get now is 'Error: value for ‘File1.tif’ not found'

Comment: try `list.files("/Users/Rob/Documents/BMBT5130/Data", full.names=T, pattern="tif$")`

Comment: maRtin, thank you  that worked!

Comment: Happy tp hear! I would be happy about an upvote/accepted answer in order to mark this question as "solved".

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments:

```
list.files("/Users/Rob/Documents/BMBT5130/Data", full.names=T, pattern="tif$")
```

should make your code work.

Make sure to set `full.names=T` to ensure that you get the entire path name and if you are working woth tif files, think about only searching files that end with "tif" (i.e. exclude tix.aux files).