# How do you load multiple rasters in [r] using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, raster

I am trying to load 144 rasters (.tif) using a loop that refers to lists, but running into errors. Note that my directory only has these 144 .tif files in it, and there are portions of each filename that are unique. I'm not sure how to best create a minimally reproducible example for this, so I've abbreviated directories and file names.

first I loaded "raster" package and set my working directory,
then I also set a variable 'path' equal to my working directory.
Next, I created a list of the files in the directory

```
setwd("T:/sample/geotiffs")
path<-"T:/sample/geotiffs"
rastlist <- list.files(path=path, pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)
```

I tried to write my code with syntax from a previous post:  [File not found in R raster loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707539/file-not-found-in-r-raster-loop)

```
for (jj in 1:length(mget(rastlist)))  {
  x[jj] <- raster(paste0(rastlist[jj]))
}
```

However, I got the following error about missing the first file: 
"Error: value for ‘T:/sample/geotiffs/geotiff1.tif’ not found"

I also tried coding it this way without the mget() and paste0(),

```
x<-vector(mode="logical",length=144)
for(i in 1:length(rastlist))  {
  x[i]<-raster(rastlist[i])
}
```

However, I am getting 50+ warnings "1: In x[i] <- raster(rastlist[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Any ideas?  After I run this code my vector, x, seems to be a vector with 144 random integers and I am not sure why - perhaps I need a better way to initiate a blank vector 'x' with length equal to my rastlist?

Comment: How about `foo <- lapply(rastlist, raster)`?

Comment: I think the error might be caused by the fact that you cannot save raster objects in a vector (I think it has to do with the fact that rasters are S4 objects); however, you can do it in a list. @Lyngbakr code should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(raster)
f <- list.files(path=path, pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)
r <- lapply(f, raster)
```

If the rasters have the same extent and resolution, you might want to do this instead

```
s <- stack(f)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, Lyngbakr and Jonathan,

Comment: Thank you Robert, Lyngbakr and Jonathan!   I see that the post with the for loop code dealt with non-spatial data, so yes, that code probably did not work due to dealing with S4 objects perhaps.  When I use the lapply(x,raster) method, I get a long list that looks correct.  However, i would like to select elements (single rasters) from the list based on name portions (pattern=).  I am getting a NULL when I try attr(allrasters,"names").    Any directions you can point me?

Comment: That is a different question. You can probably do `i <- grep(pattern, f)`

Comment: Thank you Robert,  I tried grep(), but it yields a vector of the numbers associated with the subset of vectors I am trying to access. I'm not sure how to work with that.  I found a work around that requires more code typing, but will work, see my next posted question if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904916/how-do-you-write-multiple-rasters-in-r

Comment: Robert, you were right, I can use grep() to extract rasters based on a wildcard in the name after I load them, I stumbled across info on subsetting in "R for Dummies" that reminded me of doing it this way, I wasn't thinking that way before:  allrasters[grep("BLUE",allrasters)]   Thanks for the pointers!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`x <- purrr:map(rastlist, raster)`