# How do you write multiple rasters in [r]?

Tags: r, list, lapply, raster

I am using lapply() to load 144 rasters as in my previous post: 
[How do you load multiple rasters in [r] using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887908/how-do-you-load-multiple-rasters-in-r-using-a-for-loop)

```
library(raster)
rastlist <- list.files(path=path, pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)
allrasters <- lapply(rastlist, raster)
```

allrasters ends up being a large list with 144 elements, of which 'name' looks like one of the attributes, I pasted the last (144th) element output below.

[[144]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 405, 345, 139725  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : -971895, -961545, 1463535, 1475685  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : T://abbreviatedpath/sample.tif 
names      : wildcard1_name_wildcard2 
values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)

I would like to do some processing on subsets of these rasters based on wildcards in the names.  i.e., I would like to mask those with wildcard1=x and save that output as the input raster name appended with "_m".  Later I would like to mosaic a subset of my allrasters list based on wildcard2=y.

My efforts to extract a list of rasters based on a pattern in the names from
 the already-loaded list of rasters (allrasters) failed.

```
rast.x<-grep("x",allrasters)
```

yeilds a vector of the 6 list numbers that correlate to the rasters I am trying to extract into a subset.  Maybe this is a better approach?

The only work-around I have found is to approach with a different process/pipeline:
First create subset lists, then load rasters in subset lists with lapply, then apply functions to rasters in subset lists with lapply, like here:

```
rastlist.HIGH <- list.files(path=path, pattern='HIGH', full.names=TRUE)
allrast.HIGH <- lapply(rastlist.HIGH, raster)
allrast.HIGH_m<-lapply(allrast.HIGH,mask,HIGH_mask,updatevalue=NA,updateNA=FALSE)
```

This process seems to be working, except now I am stuck on how to write the rasters in the list allrast.HIGH_m
The post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301956/write-multiple-rasters-in-r never seemed to be resolved, and perhaps it didn't work because it of the using-a-for-loop-on-an-S4-object issue.
The lapply() approach to write all these rasters does not seem to be working:

```
lapply(allrast.HIGH_m, writeRaster(filename=paste0(path),"/masked/",names(allrast.HIGH_m),"_m"), format="GTiff"))
```

This code gives me the error: Error: unexpected ')' in "lapply(allrast.HIGH_m, writeRaster(filename=paste0(path),"/masked/",names(allrast.HIGH_m),"_m"), format="GTiff"))"

Any ideas on how to write multiple rasters that are not stacked, nor that are the same extent, from a list?  And give them names which are the input name appended with something?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code, it should work.

```
lapply(allrast.HIGH_m, function (x) writeRaster(x, filename=paste0(path,"/masked/",names(x),"_m"), format="GTiff"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I didn't know you could use lapply with 'function (x)" like that!  I am getting this error "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"missing", "character"’"  I'll try to work through it a bit more over the weekend - I found some similar questions/answers posted, but not this exact error message.

Comment: Note that I am able to write a single raster from allrast.HIGH_m:  writeRaster(allrast.HIGH_m[[1]],filename='T/abbrevpath/HIGH_test_m.tif',format="GTiff")

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to add the `x` before `filename` in the `writeRaster` function. I edited the post with that modification. It should work now.

Comment: That worked!  Awesome!  And, I can use grep() to extract rasters based on a wildcard in the name after I load them, I stumbled across info on subsetting in "R for Dummies" that reminded me of doing it this way, I wasn't thinking that way before:  allrasters[grep("BLUE",allrasters)]   I really appreciate the help in getting past the logjam!