# Is there an issue with raster::writeRaster writing raster stacks in R4.2?

Tags: r, raster, geotiff

I am using some older code to write a raster stack with bylayer = T and I havent bothered to migrate it to terra yet so I am still using raster. This used to work fine:

`raster::writeRaster(stack(rastList3), names(rastList3),  bylayer = T, overwrite = TRUE, format = "GTiff")`

Now it throws the hard to decipher error:
*"Error in if (tolower(e) %in% c(".tiff", ".tif")) { :
the condition has length > 1"*

Replies to similar error message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848442/r-warning-lengthx-2-1-in-coercion-to-logical1) suggest it seems to have to do with R 4.2 but I am not fully sure that is what is happening.  I can get it to write one layer at a time using

`dsn <- here("Clipped_ENVData/Mask2022//")`

`nameT = paste(dsn, names(rastList3), ".tiff", sep = "")`

`writeRaster(rastList3[[3]], nameT[[3]], overwrite = TRUE)`

but it wont write bylayer from the stack of 10 rasters :(

Does anyone know if there is a workaround in the writeRaster function that needs to be fixed or is it something broken in my code?

Comment: UPDATE: the code also seems to work if I let it write the default grd files. Only get the error with format = "GTiff".

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug. It goes away if you update the "raster" package to version 3.6-5. That is currently the development version. You can install that version with

```
install.packages('raster', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Answer (score 1):

OH-KAY. I also found the answer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904987/7159344) which helped me work out my solution:

`lapply(rastList3, function(x) writeRaster(x, filename=paste0(dsn,names(x)), format="GTiff", overwrite = TRUE))`

While updating to a development version might fix the bug, I was hesitant as it possibly could create more headaches in other places.